# How can I use google analytics to tell me how many people come from another, specific, site?

Tags: google-analytics

I am super new to GA, like I didn't even install it, just inherited it, and I'm trying to figure out how to tell if visits are being referred/just happen to be coming from a specific website. I want to find how many people come from one site to my site. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1247839?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are logged into Google Analytics you can visit:

> Acquisition -> All Referrals

That gives you a list of all the sites that have sent referral traffic.  You can choose the option at the bottom of the page to show up to 5000 of them at once.  If you are looking for a specific one, you can sort the list by name -- just click on the "source" header.

You can click on just that particular referrer site to see a graph of the number of referrals from it over time.